# AdapterViewFlipper stops flipping after two clicks

Tags: android, kotlin, viewflipper, android-viewflipper

I have a simple AdapterViewFlipper with an onClickListener attached to its items.

When i click it should flip through all of the numbers in `data` array, "one" through to "seven".

It is only flipping on first two clicks up to "three". After that my `adapterViewFlipper` stops clicking and no flips occur. What am i doing wrong?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adapterViewFlipper = findViewById<AdapterViewFlipper>(R.id.activity_main_flipper)
        adapterViewFlipper.adapter = FlipperAdapter()
        
        val item = adapterViewFlipper.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view)

        item.setOnClickListener {
            adapterViewFlipper.showNext()
        }
    }

    class FlipperAdapter() : BaseAdapter() {

        private val data = arrayOf("one", "two", "three", "four","five","six","seven")

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return data.size
        }

        override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
            return data[p0]
        }

        override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
            return p0.toLong()
        }

        override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(getAppInstance()).inflate(R.layout.flipper_item, null)
            val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view)
            textView.setText(data[p0])
            return view
        }
    }
}
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <AdapterViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp">

    </AdapterViewFlipper>


</LinearLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:text="hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first create the activity, you're searching for `R.id.textView` inside your `AdapterViewFlipper`, and setting the click listener on that. But that `TextView` is created when `getView` in your adapter inflates the `flipper_view` layout.

When you flip to another view, `getView` inflates another copy of the layout, and that instance of `textView` doesn't have the click listener set on it, because it's a new view. I don't know why clicking would work more than once, but that's what I'd look into.

Try setting the click listener in `getView` instead - you'll need to make `adapterViewFlipper` visible to it (or call a `showNext` function in the activity that flips it, something like that)